STIGViewer 2.18 will not open
Hey guys I am new to STIGViewer on MAC to the best of my knowledge I have installed everything correctly for Java, JDK, JavaFX, you name it. I am very familiar with STIG on windows devices but I am not for MAC. I can't get STIGViewer to open at all and I honestly do not know where the issue is. I have followed several instructions however, they could be a little outdated. I have tried to uninstall everything and reinstall it, maybe I am not understanding the simple things. I am also not a MAC user.
When I try to open it from the folder I choose open with Java and nothing. I have also tried opening it from terminal and this is what I get.
java -jar STIGViewer-2.18.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile STIGViewer-2.18.jar
this is my current java version:
java --version
java 23.0.1 2024-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 23.0.1+11-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing)
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, starting from scratch, still the same issue.
